# Fluent NHibernate One-To-One with only one foreign column

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 one-to-one tables in my db, and only one of them has foreign key to another table.
Here is an example of what I have

Table 1: **Container**
 - Id (PK)

Table 2: **Item**
- Id (PK)
- ContainerId (FK)

Can I configure their relations as one to one to have following models mapped:

```
public class Container{
     public virtual int Id {get;set;}
     public virtual Item Item {get;set;}
}

public class Item{
     public virtual int Id {get;set;}
     public virtual Container {get;set;}
}
```

I can configure *Item* to have one *Container,* because it has explicit column for this, but how it can be done for *Container*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is not a true one to one relationship.  Both primary keys must be the same in both tables for it to be a one to one. Container.Id != Item.Id.  That is a `many-to-one`.

In your item mapping you would have something like this:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
References(x => x.Container);
```

Your `Container` mapping would be similar.

http://www.jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/

Comment: Is it possible to map my example models and database to look like one-to-one?